# I got my Android Emulator to work but it keeps having problems installing an apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apk, android-api-levels

This is sort of an update on the last post that I made about my Android Emulator issues. I got my emulator to work by making my device a Nexus 5X and turning my API level down to 28. However, I seemed to have solved one problem and then caused another. Judging by the error message the emulator is having a problems installing the apk:

10:14 AM    Session 'app': Error Installing APK

When I looked into it a bit more and found this error message:

06/28 10:12:48: Launching app The APK file C:\Users\User Name\AndroidStudioProjects\Speewaywebapp\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK

What should I do about this? Does anyone need to see any code?

Comment: It sounds like the APK didn't build due to a compilation error

Comment: Do I need to post some code of my app?